# With enough copper wire, can I attach one end to one side of a 9V battery, then circle the earth and connect it back?

Tags: batteries, current, wire

This is a dead serious question I have not been able to find an answer to: if I had enough wire, could I make electricity pass through if I connected one end to a small 9V battery and then circled the earth and put the other end to the other side of the battery?

If not, how do you calculate how long a current can travel before it's "lost"?

Comment: AWG 22 (0.026 inch diameter) wire has resistance 53ohm/km. The length of wire around earth would be 40 000km. The resistance of wire then 2Mohm. The current drawn from battery 4uA. Result: You can safely do the experiment.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický - Hi, Thanks for adding value on the site. However that isn't a comment, it's an answer and answers are not an [allowed use of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) (i.e. you're not improving the question or asking the OP for clarification). If you have any questions on that rule, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer, but IMO: Dead is too casual to discuss a gravely serious matter like that. You have a conductor between two potential. The current won't stop flowing until Michael Faraday and Alessandro Volta come back and take it with them.

Comment: With a wire around the Earth, you will get an antenna that will receive quite a few of electromagnetic power. Your battery will be totally lost against it - and the whole thing will be quite dangerous in solar storms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never lost: for every electron that leaves the negative terminal and enters one end of the wire, another electron will exit the other end of the wire and enter the positive terminal. Instantaneously! The length of the wire is irrelevant. Why instantaneously? Because the battery is so small, its distance within it (with respect to the speed of light) is practically 0.

When you initially connect the battery, it doesn't see the resistance of the wire (as other have calculated), it sees the capacitance of the two nearby ends of the wire with respect the earth ground. The first electron to leave the negative terminal of the battery goes into that capacitance. And the capacitance of the other end of the wire is what provides the electron that enters the positive terminal. That's why it's instantaneous - it doesn't have to wait for the current to travel along the wire.

Indeed, for the first 0.1 second or so, it makes no difference whether the wire is complete or is broken at the far end of the earth! Only after about 200 ms (the time that it takes to go around the Earth at close to the speed of light) would the current either continue (if the wire is complete) or stop (if the wire is broken at the far end of the Earth).

Comment: Electricity in a conductor does not move at the speed of light in a vacuum.

Comment: I know that. I just didn't want to add to the complexity of the explanation, so I didn't mention it.

Comment: Could you please explain a little your last paragraph ? because I read the first paragraph and it made sense to me, you're saying that essentially for one electron to move from the negative terminal of the battery, another electron has to move at the same time from the very end of the wire to the positive terminal of the battery, like a water hose, water gets out from one end and gets in from another end. But then you say on your last paragraph that for the first 0.1 seconds we wont know if the current is shut off or still on ?

Comment: I just though of using the same water hose analogy, what you said on your last paragraph is basically what happens when you shut off your water hose bib ? the water hose is still gonna shoot the water remaining inside, its not going to stop right when you stop your hose bib, the water inside still needs to travel to the outside, is this what you meant on your last paragraph ?

Comment: If you're comfortable with the water hose analogy, then consider a very long hose filled with water as the wire, and a pump as the battery. There is a valve in the middle of the hose, very far from the pump. When you first turn on the pump, it starts adding water in the hose end next to the pump's outlet, and removing water from the hose end next to the inlet. At this point, there is no way of knowing whether the valve is open or closed, because, in either case, the pump can move water. Continued below.

Comment: Continuation:  It's only later we can tell: if the hose is over-pressurized on one side and nearly empty on the other side, and the flow stops, then the valve is closed; if the the hose pressure is just slightly different and the water keeps on flowing, then we know that the valve is open.

Answer (score 8):

The [circumference of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_circumference) is about 40,000 km. Resistance of 12 AWG (3.3 mm<sup>2</sup>) copper wire is about 5.168 mΩ per meter*.

This works out to 206 kΩ.

With a 9V battery, that would be a current of 43 µA.

Your question has one sort of ambiguous term: *lost*. What do you mean by *lost*? For some applications, 43 µA is enough. Certainly to keep a low-power microcontroller and a few peripherals operating in sleep mode. For other applications, that current would be woefully inadequate, and thus might be considered *lost*.

*<sub>Ref: Omni Calculator's [wire resistance calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/physics/wire-resistance).</sub>

Comment: You would also have a single turn around the entirety of Earth's magnetic field which varies enough on a short time scale to induce some interesting voltages in your wire.

Comment: But no current would actually be *lost* along the way, because that's not how current works.  It just wouldn't flow in the first place.  (At least once any relevant capacitance is charged up...)  If the insulation on the wire is real, not infinite resistance, tiny amounts of current could bypass going the long way around the Earth and connect to each other through the insulation and the ground / water / air. But that's negligible vs. 206 kΩ, and the current measured a portion of the wire near the battery terminals would still be 43 µA. (Or *slightly* higher, from the large parallel resistance)

Comment: You can, of course, use thicker wire.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz ordinarily: no. In the case of a major solar eruption: maybe. But with wire so thin, there's a good chance it would just fizzle a section of the wire without managing to set anything *else* on fire.

Answer (score 7):

Electrical Current is not lost. It can only be converted to other forms of energy. The law of conservation of energy.

In order for you to be able to connect a battery of any size with a wire around the globe and still see a working system, is to calculate the resistance of the conductor. In a perfect system, a wire would have no resistance so it would work without reducing the voltage or absorbing the current, so to speak, converting the energy into heat.

But wires are not perfect. A wire is pretty much a resistor. Any given size copper wire will have a resistance per foot that you can use to calculate the resistance which in term limits the available current in the system. The physically bigger the copper wire the lower the resistance. So while a thin wire around the world would make your 9V battery seem weak, a stupid huge wire would not.

A 4/0 or 0000 AWG wire (largest standard wire on most charts) at almost half an inch thick and resistance of 0.05 ohms per 1000 feet, wrapped around the world at 24000 miles, would still be like a 6k ohm resistor. You could still ***weakly*** light up an led with that (at around 1 mA).

With enough copper to reduce the cumulative resistance to near 0, you could theoretically wrap a single comedically thick wire around the earth once and use it like if it didn't interfere at all.

Side note, resistance in a conductor will vary by temperature too. Magnetic coupling and interference can induce voltages and this current in your wire. A 24000 mile long wire will be quite the antenna.

Comment: How much copper and/or aluminum would it take to build a bus-bar with only say 1 ohm of resistance?  6000x the cross-section area of 0000 AWG.  sqrt(6000) is about 77 (area scales with radius^2), so we're talking a diameter of 38 to 39 inches of solid copper.  That's very close to 1 metre.  At this point you're basically building a bridge (like for people to walk on).  So yes, comically large.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about exact formulas, but I believe we should consider described setup as not just a "huge resistor". Other aspects to consider:

- Capacitor behavior: on such a huge size, we can't discard it. So, the schema seems to be a resistor with capacitor connected in parallel
- Despite the fact our battery is DC source, on a connection moment we have a short wave of AC coming. How to check: take a transformer, 9V battery, then connect the battery to the low side. On high-side, there will be a short peak (so, do NOT touch the high-side at that very moment!)
- Once we have that AC wave traveling through, our wire may behave as an antenna, dissipating part of the energy to the Universe
- Any buttery has limited amount of energy - is it enough to charge the capacitor, lose via antenna and still observe potentials on both ends?
- How close the wire to Earth surface? It may cause induction effect to be taken into consideration

Sorry again not showing formulas here, just more questions. But my inner feeling is "no way to get anything on another end".