# Minimum resistance of copper regardless of thickness

Tags: resistance, conductivity

In a system where you have an unlimited amount of copper, is there a minimum or floor to the resistance?

Scenario would be a wire 24000 miles long, attempting to keep the overall resistance below 1 ohm. Or 1 AU long. Etc.

Is there a point where adding more copper in parallel would not decrease the resistance? Or would it just decrease linearly with no bottom? If there is a limit, why?

Let's ignore practicality.

Comment: This doesn't sound like you, Passerby. What's up?

Comment: @elliot ? What do you mean?

Comment: @Passerby Is this a circumequatorial wire, perhaps? You wouldn't be trying to help out [mira](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/595704/38098), would you? ;)

Comment: @jonk inspired by it. It peaked my curiosity regarding possible limits.

Comment: @Passerby Perhaps a simpler way to consider your question is to imagine two specified contact points of specified diameter on a copper sheet of specified thickness. As the sheet expands on all sides, further and further away from the two contact points, how does the resistance between those contact points vary in the limit of an infinite sheet? And does the 2D answer provide insight into a similar question posed into 3D?

Comment: @jonk you mean model it like an ever increasing matrix of resistors?

Comment: @Passerby Could be numerically approached like that, I suppose. I was thinking more as setting up the integral equations and solving. But sure.

Comment: We don't know your other hypothetical constraints; ultimately resistivity is expressed as the resistance of a cube; but you can't build a 24,000 mile cube of copper using only material found on the (this) planet. At some point you run out of copper.  If you adopt a more reasonable (say square mile cross section, whatever that is in kcmil)  you can easily calculate the resistance. So I guess I don't understand what you're really asking. Could you clarify the question?

Answer (score 4):

No, not if you allow superconducting contacts on the ends of the copper bus bar.

If you don't allow that, then you have to consider the geometry of the ends and how the current would spread from however it is connected.

Comment: Yeah.  Not circular but a thin flat sheet and the issue is not the flow inside, but how you get electrons into sheet.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Resistance is \$\frac{\rho l}{A}\$, where \$\rho \$ is resistivity, A is crosssectional area to the current, and l is the path length.  The limit is zero, as A grows huge.

Comment: So you could continue to add copper to meet a target resistance, with only money/effort/literal space being the constraints?

Comment: That's true.  I suppose there may be edge effects where the signal is connected,  probably best modeled as a resistivity field and finite elements

Comment: More Area means more atoms which means an easier path for electrons to flow.